# How to pass a list element as reference?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am passing a single element of a list to a function. I want to modify that element, and therefore, the list itself.

```
def ModList(element):
    element = 'TWO'

l = list();
l.append('one')
l.append('two')
l.append('three')
print l
ModList(l[1])
print l
```

But this method does not modify the list. It's like the element is passed by value. The output is:

```
['one','two','three']
['one','two','three']
```

I want that the second element of the list after the function call to be 'TWO':

```
['one','TWO','three']
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There's no syntax for doing what you ask, but there are lots of ways to modify a part of a list. If you ask a question about the specific problem you're using this for, someone will come up with the most intuitive and elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

The explanations already here are correct.  However, since I have wanted to abuse python in a similar fashion, I will submit this method as a workaround.

Calling a specific element from a list directly returns a copy of the value at that element in the list.  Even copying a sublist of a list returns a new reference to an array containing copies of the values.  Consider this example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a[2]
>>> b
3
>>> c = a[2:3]
>>> c
[3]
>>> b=5
>>> c[0]=6
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Neither `b`, a value only copy, nor `c`, a sublist copied from `a`, is able to change values in `a`.  There is no link, despite their common origin.

However, numpy arrays use a "raw-er" memory allocation and allow views of data to be returned.  A view allows data to be represented in a different way while maintaining the association with the original data.  A working example is therefore

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = a[2]
>>> b
3
>>> b=5
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> c = a[2:3]
>>> c
array([3])
>>> c[0]=6
>>> a
array([1, 2, 6, 4])
>>>
```

While extracting a single element still copies by value only, maintaining an array view of element `2` is referenced to the original element `2` of `a` (although it is now element `0` of `c`), and the change made to `c`'s value changes `a` as well.

Numpy `ndarray`s have many different types, including a generic object type.  This means that you can maintain this "by-reference" behavior for almost any type of data, not only numerical values.

Answer (score 5):

Python [doesn't do pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). Just do it explicitly:

```
l[1] = ModList(l[1])
```

Also, since this only changes one element, I'd suggest that `ModList` is a confusing name.

Answer (score 5):

Python is a pass by value language hence you can't change the value by assignment in the function `ModList`.  What you could do instead though is pass the list and index into `ModList` and then modify the element that way

```
def ModList(theList, theIndex) :
  theList[theIndex] = 'TWO'

ModList(l, 1)
```

Comment: thats not quite consistent. "Python is a pass by value langauge", hence the original list can be modified when passed as paramter?!?

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can also consider to let the function both modify and return the modified list. This makes the caller code more readable:

```
def ModList(theList, theIndex) :
          theList[theIndex] = 'TWO'
    return theList

l = ModList(l, 1)
```

Comment: Mixing up operations that mutate their argument and operations that return a new object is horrible